# Handling exceptions in BlockingCollection

Tags: c#

I have a blocking `BlockingCollection` that I use to process a queue (i.e. sending emails).

```
BlockingCollection<ItemQueue> queue = new BlockingCollection<ItemQueue>();
Thread threadQueue = new Thread(ProcessQueue);
threadQueue.Start();

private void ProcessQueue()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var item = queue.Take();

        process(item); 
    }
}

public void process(ItemQueue item)
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Basically I run a separate thread where I wait for an element in the queue (somewhere there is an `Add()` call). Then I process that item.
This function might raise an exception: if we're talking about emails, for example, the `Send()` may fails.

I would like to handle this situation in two different ways, depending on the specific application:

1. repeat the process function with the same item until it completes without any exception
2. put this item at the end of the queue in order to try again later, but process the other items now

Is there a better approach that handles these behaviors natively?

Comment: Sorry to be unclear. I mean if my approach is correct about the use of `BlockingCollection` for this type of behaviors. I'm able to implement them, but I wonder if there is a better approach that handle these behaviors natively.

Comment: http://Programmers.stackexchange.com would be better place for this question. Reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211788/code-review-vs-stackoverflow

Comment: @mortb when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat: well, yes of course. This question should have been migrated instead. But since it now has gotten an answer it might be a bit late for that...I would think it is better just to leave it as it is.

Comment: @mortb There is zero reason to migrating this question. It is about coding a solution to a very specific problem. OP describes solutions that he wanted to implement. He does not have working code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: alright then, I thought it was more of an architectural thing..I would think that writing a good queue with retry functionality is a bit more complicated than it at first seems and that it could need more design than this...but I haven't really written one my self

Comment: @mortb I'd use [dataflow from TLP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) for something like that, but suggesting this would probably be too much of an architectural change.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: yes, that's more my thought, he says nothing about how he will be performing his operations (send mail?). Will these be blocking operations, maybe he would actually benefit from running a number of them in parallel etc...(at work we have a homemade (not written by me :)  ) queue solution that is...well...colorful..) I think there is more to this than meets the eye, someday this solution maybe installed at a number of clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches have their shortcomings:

- The first approach may stall the queue indefinitely in case an item has permanent delivery problems
- The second approach will keep an item with permanent delivery problems in the queue indefinitely

A better approach would establish a separate blocking collection for items that failed, push them into that collection on exception, along with the exception object, and forget about them. A separate thread would take these items off the queue, analyze the exception, and decide what to do next. It could schedule re-sending at an appropriate time, push the item back if its failure count is under some fixed number, file the message for analysis by administrators, or simply discard it, depending on the needs of your system.

Comment: It makes sense. I'm going to create a second blocking collection for items that failed.